# how do express “multiple” in predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic

I hope you can give me some tips on how to translate part of the following sentence into predicate logic:

“No woman loves a man that loves **multiple** women”.

Which quantifier would you use to express the part “multiple”? It of course means “more than one”, so the existential quantifier (expressing: at least one) as such does not seem enough... Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me!

Comment: "more than one" is "at least two".

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree, but then my question becomes: how do I express that? Sorry, just starting out with predicate logic, so maybe the answer should be obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase that part as

> There are two different women loved by the man

$\exists x\exists y:$ Woman$(x)\, \land\,$Woman$(y)\, \land\, \lnot(x=y)\,\land\,$Love$(m,x)\, \land\,$Love$(m, y)$

Comment: I would instead write $\exists x,y\in\text{Women}$, but it's the same concept.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense!